# How would we translate 'we could always' in Spanish? So 'we could always try it this way', or 'they could always get divorced'

Tags: traducción

Would it simply be 'siempre', as in English, or is there another way to say 'failing xxx, we could always xxx'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *siempre* or the phrase *en todo caso*. *En todo caso* is not equivalent to *siempre* but they are sufficiently alike in these sentences. They work with the indicative or the conditional:

- *Siempre podemos tratar de esta manera.*
- *En todo caso podríamos tratar de esta manera.*

Some people prefer an indirect style:

- *Siempre existe la posibilidad de divorciarse.*
- *En todo caso tienen la chance de divorciarse.*

Comment: I think "En cualquier caso" would fit better to indicate that that possibility is always available.

Comment: In English it means in any case, at any time; in any event (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/always).  So *en todo caso, en cualquier caso, de todas maneras, de todos modos,* all seem possible.  In some situations, it could be a quirky proposal: *¿Y si nos divorciáramos?  Esa opción siempre existe.*